# best practices for tier development in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have 3 projects

- website ( website )
- BusinessLogic (    Class Lib)
- UserControls (web application) //    needs to be external

1) In order to debug the UserControls from website. Is it true all i need to is add a project reference from website to UserControls. This was working, but stop not sure why. Or shall i use a build event and copy the dll into the bin

2) If BusinessLogic  require "thirdparty.dll" which currently lives in Website/bin. Is it best practise to add reference from Business Logic to "Website/bin/thirdparty.dl" or shall i just copy it into BusinessLogic project

Answer (score 1):

I like to follow the clear dependence way.

If business logic depends on a third party library, put it there.

You website depends only on business logic, leave it as such.

Comment: thanks, clear dependence? so are you saying add the dll and not use project references.

Comment: I mean reference the library in the project that directly depends on it. The build should be able to copy it down to the "root" project.